# Use Stone-Weierstrass theorem to show that $f$ will be $0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

Fix a real number $\lambda>0$. Let $f\in C[0,1]$ satisfy $\int_0^1 t^{n\lambda}f(t)dt=0$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$. What can be deduced about the function $f$?

Claim: $f$ will be $0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

*Let $A$ be the set of polynomials in $t^\lambda$. Note that $A$ is a subalgebra of $C[0,1]$ that separates points and vanishes at nowhere, so $A$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ by Stone-Weierstrass. **Thus, we have a set of polynomials in $A$ such that converges uniformly to $f(t)$.**

Since $\int_0^1 t^{n\lambda}f(t)dt=0$ for **all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$**, **we do not know that if $\int_0^1p_n(t^\lambda)f(t)dt=0$ for all polynomial $p_n(t^\lambda)$**.

Since by Stone-Weierstrass theorem there exists a set of polynomials in set $A$ that converges uniformly to $f$, $\forall\epsilon\geq 0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, $|f-p_n|\leq\epsilon$.

**Note $\exists N'\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $\int_0^1t^{n\lambda}f(t)dt=0$ for all $n\geq N'$. Let $M=max\{N,N'\}$, we have $\int_0^1p_{n\geq M}(t^\lambda)f(t)dt=0=\int_0^1f(t)^2dt=0$.**

Since $f$ is continuous, so is $f^2$. Since $\int_0^1f(t)^2dt=0$ with $f^2\geq 0$, $f^2=0$ and $f=0$.

Is the above proof correct especially the highlighted ones (emboldened)?

Comment: I think this is not quite right: there are some equalities that should involve epsilons somehow. Specifically you should have something like $\left | \int_0^1 f(t) p_\epsilon(t) dt - \int_0^1 f(t)^2 dt \right |<\epsilon$, but then the first term is given to be zero and the result follows by taking $\epsilon$ to be arbitrary.

Comment: That's not Weierstrass, it's Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: @zhw Ok, Thank you. Will be corrected. But does the proof look ok? Is there any problem with the statements up there? Thank you!

Comment: Your fourth paragraph: "Not true that" should be changed to "we do not know that"

Comment: @zhw. ok, thank you so much for correcting! Does everything else look ok? needs to be corrected?

Comment: @zhw. Is the idea correct: since $p_n$ approximate $f$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we don't really care what it does for only finitely many $n$, right? Thank you!

Comment: @2ndaccount The problem is that maybe all $p_n$ contain the missing terms

Comment: You've confused the $n$ in $p_n$ with the $n$ in $t^{n\lambda}.$ Your paragraph "Note $\exists N'\in\mathbb{N}$, such that ..." is kind of hopelessly wrong.

Comment: @clark you are right. but I don't know what to do with this "all but finitely many $n$..."

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381535/int-01-tn-lambdaftdt-0-for-all-but-finitely-many-n  See my answer there.

Comment: @zhw. For some $N$ and beyond $\int_0^1 t^n\lambda f(t)dt=0$, and for some other $N$ and beyond, say $N'$, $|p_n-f|>\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes but the $n$ in $p_n$ has nothing to do with $t^{n\lambda}.$

Comment: @zhw. Is this the same concern as clark mentioned? I read your comment on that post, but why did you contain $t^{n\lambda}$ but just $t^\lambda$? Are they the same? Also clark's comment was my concern too... I'm not sure how to deal the this "all but finitely many" situation...